# How to insert date and time in European format into SQL Server from C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

Here's my query:

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(DATE) 
                            VALUES (convert(datetime, '{0}')";

sql = string.Format(sql, myDate);
```

`myDate` is a C# `DateTime` object and has this value before the `string.format`:

[image]

`MY_TABLE` has a DATE column as a `DateTime` type.

I got this error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I need to store the `myDate`value in a format like: `31/12/2013 23:59:00` into MY_TABLE.

Comment: this is a trick: when handling database dates, always use locale database setting and always in UTC format. Then, upon reading, apply the user locale and it's timezone. This way no matter where the db is, you will always have the correct times.

Comment: Data in datetime is not STORED in any format, but as a binary. You can SHOW it in some format.

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić +1. That is correct.

Comment: Never build your sql statement like that! Always use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)!

Answer (score 6):

better to use sql parameters

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(DATE) 
                            VALUES (@DATE)";
```

add the parameter to your SqlCommand with [**`SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue` Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", myDate);
```

OR, with [**`SqlParameterCollection.Add` Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add.aspx)

```
   command.Parameters.Add("@DATE",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myDate
```

Comment: Yes. It is the safest way to handle parameters instead of passing them in a string.

Comment: I would use the .Add() function instead of AddWithValue:
command.Parameters.Add("@DATE", SqlDbtype.DateTime).Value = myDate;

Comment: @FabianBigle  my date is DateTime and database expect DateTime so why you telling so?

Comment: @Damith There are heaps of links out there (Google Add vs AddWithValue), where the consensus is the same: Use Add() over AddWithValue().

Comment: As long as it's not deprecated, use whichever one you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss")
```

For a list of the parameters see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). (Scroll down a bit to see the table.)

(And it is advised to use `Parameters.AddWithValue` to avoid SQL injection etc.)